# how to specify which child class this object belong to after retrieving from a hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

i have a parent class called Course, and two child class PostgradCourse and UndergradCourse.
i have a hashmap HashMap courses; i store all the postgradCourse and undergradCourse objects in the hashmap.

i want to retrieve an undergradCourse object from the hashmap using the key.
Course course =  courses.get(courseCode);
then i want to call a method in the UndergradCourse class, setUnits() method
course.setUnits();
but the compiler say cannot find symbol- method setUnit()

im pretty sure the problem is the compiler is looking for a method setUnit() in the Course class instead of UndergradCourse class

i did this but its not working
UndergradCourse course = courses.get(courseCode);
results in incompatible type

so how can i retrieve undergradCourse object from the hashmap as an undergradCourse object instead of course object?
so then i can call a method inside the child class

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you program in Java, you can use the **instanceof** operator the determine whether the object is of a certain type.

```
Course course = courses.get(courseCode)
if(course instanceof UndergradCourse)
{
    UndergradCourse undergradCourse = (UndergradCourse)course;
    // do you stuff with the undergrad course
}
```

**Note:** Depending on the actual type of the object is breaking object oriented programing. It's not considered good style.

Answer (score 1):

The map stores two different types of course. When you retrieve a course from the map, you don't know which type of course you've retrieved.

To fix this, if you're programming in C++, there are at least three alternative ways to handle this:

1. Have two different maps: one map of undergraduate courses, and another map of postgraduate cources (instead of a single map of base courses).
2. When you get a base course from the single map, cast the object (using static_cast or dynamic_cast) to the type of subclass which you know/hope it is
3. Declare the setUnit method as virtual (perhaps pure virtual) in the abstract base course, and give it two different implementations in the subclasses: then because it's declared in the base course, you can call it on the base course object which you retrieve from the map.